# How do i get the year to change with each tournament?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, beautifulsoup

I don't understand why i am struggling with this but how do i get the year to change for each iteration. So when it goes through season 2020, all those tournaments and id's should say 2020 but its only saying the last iteration ran.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
 
seasonid = ['2021', '2020', '2019']

tournament = [] 

tid = []


for season in seasonid:
       
    url = f'https://www.espn.com/golf/schedule/_/season/{season}'
    reqs = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(reqs.text, 'html.parser')

    for link in soup.find_all('div', class_='eventAndLocation__innerCell'):
        for link2 in link.find_all('a'):
           data = link2.get('href')
           ndata = data.strip('https://www.espn.com/golf/leaderboard?tournamentId=')
           tid.append(ndata)  
     
    for link in soup.find_all('div', class_='eventAndLocation__innerCell'):
        for link2 in link.find_all('a'):
            tournamentn = link2.text
            tournament.append(tournamentn)
            
            year = season

            df1 = pd.DataFrame(tournament)
            df2 = pd.DataFrame(tid)

            df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis = 1)
            df['year'] = year
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create list with all information as tuples and at the end create final dataframe. For example:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

seasonid = ["2021", "2020", "2019"]

all_data = []
for season in seasonid:
    url = f"https://www.espn.com/golf/schedule/_/season/{season}"
    reqs = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(reqs.text, "html.parser")

    for link in soup.find_all("div", class_="eventAndLocation__innerCell"):
        for link2 in link.find_all("a"):
            tid = link2.get("href").strip(
                "https://www.espn.com/golf/leaderboard?tournamentId="
            )
            tournament = link2.text

            all_data.append((season, tournament, tid))

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data, columns=["year", "tournament", "tid"])
print(df.head().to_markdown(index=False))
```

Prints:

| year | tournament | tid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | Safeway Open | 401219793 |
| 2021 | U.S. Open | 401219333 |
| 2021 | Corales Puntacana Resort & Club Championship | 401219480 |
| 2021 | Sanderson Farms Championship | 401219794 |
| 2021 | Shriners Hospitals for Children Open | 401219795 |